# load() triggered by a button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load content using AJAX with JQuery by the first time. I have a "container webpage" and I have to show some data divided into 4 other webpages, so I wanted just to load one div of my entire "container webpage". Every page contain a button which loads the next page. So, for example, I have this simple HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Load</button>
<div id="result" onclick="loadContent()"></div>
```

And this JQuery code for one button:

```
var loadContent = function(){
   $('#result').load('http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/m44cqzrb/show/');
}
```

But when I click, nothing happens...
Can you help me? I know it should be very easy, but I'm very used to Js, not to JQuery and it's driving me crazy... Thanks in advance.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/pt2Lzmj9/4/

Comment: The click event is on the `<div>` and not the `<button>`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: It's not working in the fiddle because you used the "onLoad" option instead of one of the "No wrap" options, so the function isn't in the global scope.

Comment: And even when you fix that, it gets an error because of the same-origin policy.

Comment: @Barmar I tryed with No wrap and it's not working :(

Comment: Did you check for errors in the Javascript console? Was the error what I said in my second comment?

Comment: @GaryStorey you are right! I changed it with all your suggerences but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/gal007/pt2Lzmj9/8/

Comment: @Barmar you are right! It's a same origin policy problem! :)

Comment: You should add an answer :)

Comment: 15 pts for Barmar is a drop in the ocean =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems:

- You bound your click handler to the div, when you meant to bind it to the button.
- The `loadContent()` function isn't available from the global context.  Because you included jQuery, all the javascript gets created in local context.  Take a look at the source generated by jsfiddle, and you'll see what I mean.
- You're trying to execute a cross-domain Ajax load, which isn't generally allowed.

You should try this for your javascript instead...

```
$('#btn').click( function() {
    $('#result').load('/gal007/m44cqzrb/show/');
});
```

And change your HTML to get rid of the inline JS...

```
<button id="btn">Load</button>
<div id="result"> </div>
```

That'll work.

Comment: And the same origin policy problem too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would assign the click handler as follows.

```
$('#result').click(function() {
   $(this).load('...');
});
```

(Change '#result' to '#btn' if you wanted to handle click events on the button!)

I don't really know the 'load' function, so I'm assuming its all good.
You may wish to debug your script.  And use the developer version of jQuery so you stand a chance of understanding what's going on.

Comment: (Assuming you did want the click to be from the <div>, as Gary pointed out)

Comment: Turns out Barmar cracked it. wd :D

Answer (score 0):

You should bind onclick on that button not on the div:

```
<button id="btn" onclick="loadContent()">Load</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And load is used to load html from same domain only...